# regex.findall() does not produce the expected result

Tags: python, regex

I'm running some unit tests, but my function (regex) is not generating the result that I'm expecting.

The character class includes characters 'a', 'b', and 'c', which is what the capturing group should pick up.  However, it seems like the regex is "skipping" the 'c', and it's just returning a lone 'b'.

By the way, I'm trying to run this code in Python.

```
import re 

text = "Abcd"
def LetterCompiler(text):
  result = re.findall(r'([a-c]).', text)
  return result

print(LetterCompiler(text))
```

#expected = ['b', 'c']

#result= ['b']

Comment: Use `r'[a-c](?=.)'` or `r'[a-c](?!$)'`

Comment: from the documentation: "Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string". Your expectation would be overlapping

Comment: `.` is a "typo" in your pattern. If you do not want to match a char after the `a`/`b`/`c`, then just remove the `.`

Comment: the . is part of the requirements as 'a', 'b', and 'c' have to be followed by a character.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the `([a-c])` in the Regex matches the `b` then the `.` matches the `c` and the next attempt to match starts with the `d`. In some sense the `([a-c]).` *consumes* the `bc` and leave the RexEx to resume by looking at the `d`. The (?=.) in @anubhava's comment tells the RegEx to look for any character, but not consume it as part of the match (i.e. lookahead).

Answer (score -2):

Answer by @AdreanHHH is correct. The important part in the documentation is, that the matches must be "**non-overlapping**".